# Step progress indicator for javafx

Tags: javafx, progress-bar

I searched al stack overflow and i only found progress bars . just like progress bar in windows and ... . I am looking for a multi step progress bar. something like the ones we have in the online shopping sites when filing our information . it has for example 4 steps. 1- select product 2- fill information ... then in each step all of them are on until the step that we are in that right now. and next steps are off. is there a plugin of thrick for this in javafx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything like that out of the box. But it should be straightforward to build your own, just add the components representing the steps to a pane. Then highlight the component representing the current step (by changing its colour or image, etc).

Comment: Thanks...Yes its easy. i just though maybe there will be sth outside ready:)